# how can I programmatically determine the max field length of a property in a LINQ-to-SQL generated object?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I have a very large table with 137 fields. I am building records for this table in a Record object in VB and then trying to insert them with LINQ to SQL. But I'm unable to insert the records because one or more of the fields is too long. When I try to insert with linq to sql, I get the error: *String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.*

I have looked over the details of the error message but can't find what field is too long.

To solve this problem, I want to use reflection to loop thru each of the values for each field in the Record object and then check to see if it's too long. In order to do that, I need to programmatically access the max field length from the linq to sql object (so I know what the max size is). How can I do this? In the GUI for a given linq to sql object, I can see that each field has a serverdatatype property which stores the max value. How can I access this with code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to grab the attributes of the property and look at the `DbType` property of any applied `ColumnAttribute` to find out the "length".  e.g.

```
Account acc = new Account();
ColumnAttribute[] att = acc.GetType().GetProperty("CreditCardNumber").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), false) as ColumnAttribute[];
```

Above, I have an Account type (that maps to an account table) and a CreditCardNumber property (that maps to a CreditCardNumber column).  This property has a ColumnAttribute applied to it by L2S.

If a `ColumnAttribute` was applied, `att` above will contain one `ColumnAttribute` object.  You can find out what the `DbType` is by 'att[0].DbType'.  For example, this might be "NVarChar(100)".  You can parse that to get the 100 out of it.

#### Update:

You can also use the `MetaModel` object associated with the data context.  For example, if you already have a data context named `dbContext`, you can get at the DbType as follows:

```
 dbContext.Mapping.GetTable(typeof (Account)).RowType.GetDataMember(typeof (Account).GetProperty("CreditCardNumber")).DbType;
```

You'd still have to parse the "NVarChar(100)" text.

Comment: Don't even need reflection. You can use the MetaModel.

Comment: @usr you'd still need to use reflection to get at the `MemberInfo` of the property in question, or enumerate all the data members comparing the data member's `Name` property...